# How to apply the Identity Theorem to this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Given the function $f(z)=\exp\left(z^2-\cos\left(iz\right)-4\right)$ with the domain $|z|<10$, if we try to apply the Cauchy integral formula, we'll see that f(2) "will be"

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\frac{\exp\left(z^2-\cos\left(iz\right)-4\right)}{z-2}dz = 0$$
where $\Gamma$ is the unit circle.

However, we know that $\exp(\cdot)\ne 0$, and direct computation shows that the Cauchy integration formula does not produce the right result in this case.

I know that somehow this is related to the Identity theorem, and that perhaps some condition necessary for the Cauchy integration formula is violated, but I don't see what's going on here. Would appreciate some insight.

Comment: You can't use $\Gamma$ as the unit circle as you have $z-2$ in the denominator.

Comment: Good point, thank you. So the identity theorem I guess has nothing to do with it?

Comment: No, not really. The problem here is just that $2$ is not in the interior of the unit circle and thus the cauchy integral formula can't be applied to get $f(2)$.